# Unsupported engine, when installing eslint-plugin-react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

New react user here, I'm encountering the following error in my terminal when I install `eslint-plugin-react` and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@es-joy/jsdoccomment@0.10.8',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12 || ^14 || ^16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.3.0', npm: '8.3.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-plugin-jsdoc@36.1.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12 || ^14 || ^16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.3.0', npm: '8.3.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "postcode-pricing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Lorum Ipsum",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "start:custom": "wp-scripts start src/index.js --output-path=admin/build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^19.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "google"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  }
}
```

Is anyone able to help me make sense of these particular errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that these two packages require Node 12, 14, or 16 but your Node version is 17.

It is just warnings and packages will be properly installed just like other ones. However there might be an error caused by Node version mismatch. Best way is to temporarily use Node 16(if you use NVM).

Comment: I remember reading about potentially having to switch between node versions. I don't use `NVM` though, I currently use `Homebrew`. Thanks for the assist though, I'll try hooking up node@16 and seeing if that solves the issue.

Comment: @Beaniie It is qlso available to do version switching with brew. Run `brew install node@16` to install Node 16 and use `brew switch node 16` and `brew switch node 17` to switch versions, `brew cleanup` to remove old versions.

Comment: I didn't know you could switch using `brew switch`. Good to know, I found this post here https://ralphjsmit.com/switch-between-nodejs-versions-homebrew/#comment-1528 which talks about being able to create node aliases so you can switch between node versions with each new instance of the terminal. Though I'm not sure I'm understanding the pathing correctly at the moment. 

Comment: Just emerged from the rabbit hole of installing nvm via homebrew, for any that follow try this link. https://blog.jamesauble.com/install-nvm-on-mac-with-brew-adb921fb92cc